# Accessing the body in response of callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy request with a body. I want to access this body in my callback method through response

```
body = '{"requests":[{"indexName":"prod_products","params":"query=&tagFilters=' + tag_filter \
               + '&page=' + page_number + '&getRankingInfo=true&ruleContexts=' + rule_contexts \
               + '&facets=' + self.facets + '"}]}'

    yield Request(self.pagination_url_t, method='POST',
                      body=body)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`scrapy.http.Response` object has `request` attribute](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=Request#scrapy.http.Response).

```py
rb = response.request.body
```